# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '…: {"name":"@babel/plug'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm getting this error while creating new React App in CMD by using `create-react-app my-app` but unfortunately getting this kind of error

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:{"name":"@babel/plug'

After this CMD says `Aborting Installation.` followed by  `Deleting generated file...`

FYI, Things I've tried...

- Uninstalled Node.js package
- Downloaded Node.js version " Windows (x64) 10.15.3 LTS Recommended For Most Users" and Installed this
- Installed React JS by using CMD `npm install -g create-react-app` and done successfully.

Here is [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14QwnpSa5BlkWDax6i46R5aMx9d6WnHOlQZaLtbOwR3g) of log file which states further information on this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : npm cache clean --force